# accessing a Row, after a df conversion, in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, data-cleaning

I have the data below, having converted a single row dataframe to a RDD.
I am using PySpark 2.1.0.

```
[Row((1 - (count(YEAR_MTH) / count(1)))=0.0, 
(1 - (count(REPORTED_BY) / count(1)))=0.0, 
(1 - (count(FALLS_WITHIN) / count(1)))=0.0, 
(1 - (count(LOCATION) / count(1)))=0.0, 
(1 - (count(LSOA_CODE) / count(1)))=0.021671826625387025, 
(1 - (count(LSOA_NAME) / count(1)))=0.021671826625387025, 
(1 - (count(CRIME_TYPE) / count(1)))=0.0, 
(1 - (count(CURRENT_OUTCOME) / count(1)))=0.0, 
(1 - (count(FINAL_OUTCOME) / count(1)))=0.6377708978328174)]
```

I was trying to ascertain what percentage of values in each column is NULL, by using the following select on a dataframe to RDD conversion:

```
col_with_nulls = df.agg(*[(1 - (fn.count(c) / fn.count('*'))) 
                    for c in cols_to_categorise]).rdd
```

Thereafter, if the percentage is small, as is the case for LSOA_CODE, but almost two-thirds for FINAL_OUTCOME, then
I can safely filter the rows for the column with the small percentage, but rather impute data for column with a large percentage.

The eventual aim would be to minimise data loss. So the question is, how can I access the column and percentage from the "Row" as listed above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you alias columns inside `agg` you can get a nice-looking dict of null percetage for each column:

```
null_percentage = df.agg(*[(1 - (fn.count(c) / fn.count('*'))).alias(c) 
     for c in cols_to_categorise]).first().asDict()
```

will give you dict in form `{'LSOA_CODE': 0.021671826625387025, 'CRIME_TYPE': 0.0, ...}`

Comment: thanks. great idea. I'm still new to Pyspark so I appreciate snippets such as these.